# Xcode isn't Renaming the application properly

Tags: xcode, swift, rename, xcode6.4

[image]Sorry for the bad pictures. My Xcode project for some reason stopped renaming the actual app correctly the new name doesn't even show up an the app on my test iPhone (actual iPhone 6 plus). I could use some help?

its looks like the picture above in stead of the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name displayed on device (below app icon), add the `Bundle display name` attribute to the `Info.plist` of the project.

[image]